# Mac boot to Windows by Default

Tags: boot, boot-camp

Is there a way to configure a Bootcamped Mac Mini to boot directly into Windows rather than having it boot to OS-X by default?
(Note: uninstalling OS-X is not an option.)

Update on 03/09/2010: Options to select a startup disk are greyed out and not available, plus only the Mac OS-X partition is showing and the Bootcamp partition/disk doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the Bootcamp partition didn't show up under Startup Disk settings under Mac OS-X, I was able to select the Bootcamp settings when booted into Windows to set "Bootcamp" as the default startup disk. It shows up there, just not under OS-X.

Answer (score 5):

From within Mac OS X, fire up System Preferences.app, then navigate to "Startup Disk" and select your Boot Camp partition.  That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Question shouldn't be post here I think.

By the way you can do it by configuring startup options, they should be in **System Preferences**. Maybe the exact name of the item is **Startup Disk**.